# Borel-Cantelli Lemma Proof.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

[image]

**I struggle to understand the transition between the steps in the red box.**

Especially why the limit there, i get the intuition behind the limit, its because $A_n$ is a decreasing set ie $ A_1\supseteq \ A_2 \supseteq\ A_3\supseteq ...$ but is there any rigour to it? The union and intersection parts make sense though!

Relevant thm 1.25c) post is: [$A_n$ is an increasing set. Then what is $\ A_1\setminus A_0$ if $A_0=\emptyset$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091336/a-n-is-an-increasing-set-then-what-is-a-1-setminus-a-0-if-a-0-emptyset/1091338#1091338)

Comment: See lemma three of this link http://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/Top08/exercises/hamsandwich.pdf for a proof of the used fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not necessarily decreasing. However, if we define

$$B_n := \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$$

then $B_n$ is decreasing since

$$B_{n+1} = \bigcup_{k \geq n+1} A_k \subset \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k = B_n.$$

Since $B_n \downarrow B$ for $B:= \bigcap_{n \geq 1} B_k$, the continuity of the measure from above shows

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k \right) &= \mathbb{P}(B) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(B_n) \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k \right). \end{align*}$$

Comment: I just don't see why $P(B)=\lim_{n \to \infty} P(B_n)$. It doesnt follow from your earlier explanation. Maybe you could clarify that a little?

Comment: @user4205580 Any probability measure is continuous from above, i.e. for any sequence $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of measurable sets such that $B_1 \supseteq B_2 \supseteq B_3 \supseteq \dots$ we have $$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(B_n);$$ see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Measures_of_infinite_intersections_of_measurable_sets).